# AngularJS : Display a property value of multiple objects in an input text field, comma separated

Tags: javascript, angularjs, arrays, angular-nglist

I have an array of JSON objects in the format

`users=[{id:'1',name:'ABC'},{id:'2',name:'DEF'},............]`

I need to display the names of all users in an `input text field` comma separated as below image.

[image]

I tried using `ng-list` directive, but for that I had to first loop through the *user* objects and store all the *names* in a separate array and use that array as `ng-model` for the `<input>` element. Is there an easy, alternate way in angularjs?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A simple JS solution Use Map function to get the desired property in array then use a join over it

```
 var users=[{id:'1',name:'ABC'},{id:'2',name:'DEF'}];

 $scope.userModel = users.map(function(el){return el.name}).join(",");

 <input type="text" ng-model="userModel">
```

Comment: <input type="text" ng-model="usermodel" />  and in angular you can assign as $scope.usermodel=users.map(function(el){return el.name}).join(",") @sreehari

Comment: `$scope.userModel = users.map((e) => e.name).join(",");`   :)